# How do I properly wipe the acore_characters database and reimport it?

Tags: sql, azerothcore

I wanted to delete all character data from my server and read under a thread that the easiest way to do that was to drop the database in SQL and reimport it.  I attempted to do that and dropped the acore_characters database, created the database again, and manually ran each SQL file to populate the database with all of the needed tables.  When I ran Worldserver after doing this, I received the following errors:

> 2021-03-13 18:36:54 ERROR: WORLD: World initialized in 0 minutes 57 seconds

> 2021-03-13 18:36:54 ERROR: Your database structure is not up to date. Please make sure you've executed all queries in the sql/updates folders.

My knowledge of SQL is very limited (I've never used SQL before downloading and installing AC).  I have no idea what this error message means or what I need to do in order to fix the problem.

What did I do wrong in the process of creating the database again and how do I fix the status it is currently in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way you imported it. You probably imported the SQL dump manually but that's not the (complete) way to do it. That's why you get:

> 2021-03-13 18:36:54 ERROR: Your database structure is not up to date. Please make sure you've executed all queries in the sql/updates folders.

The DB should also be updated, by loading all SQL update files. Luckily you don't have to do it manually as the AzerothCore bash scripts do it automatically for you.

So all you have to do is actually delete everything and follow this:

https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Database-Setup

so basically after having copied and configured the `conf/config.sh` file, you can just run:

```
bash apps/db_assembler/db_assembler.sh
```

and select `5` or `import-all` ("Assemble & Import all").

This will install a fresh AC database, matching with your sources version.

---

In addition... just for your information:

This tool is also useful to update your server. After updating the sources (e.g. `git pull`) you can just run the same script and select `7` or `import-updates` ("Assemble & Import only updates") to easily update your DB.

Comment: I did attempt to use the db_assembler as well but it didn't work.  Reinstalling a fresh AC  isn't an option for me since I have made significant amounts of edits to stuff in the acore_world database and made changes to a good chunk of code as well.  This is why I attempted to do it by just working with the acore_characters database only.  I did also run all of the SQL files that were in my sql/updates folders when I did my manual import.

Comment: no need to delete the `acore_world` DB or other things, just delete again your characters DB and try to run the DB assembler again as I explained in my answer. Also I don't know what you meant by "the db_assembler didn't work". Did you get an error? You can open a separate question for that so we can help you. There is really no need to do manual imports ;)

Comment: I will open a separate question then for the errors I got when trying to run the DB assembler if I can't find a similar question open already.  It's weird because the errors seem completely unrelated to anything about the acore_characters db but I definitely used the DB assembler in my initial install and it ran with no issues.

Comment: So the db_assembler not running was just me being dumb.  Got it running and then ran into the same issue as before even after using the assembler to create the database.  I happened to notice something right as worldserver was closing that didn't show up in the server log file.  It was trying to do something with a table and transmogrification (I have the tmog module).  I ran worldserver again to see exactly what it was trying to do and figured out that I had neglected to run the SQL scripts from the module files that has acore_characters tables.

Comment: On a side note, I think there is an issue with the db assembler handling module SQL files.  It was unable to locate the filepath from my user directory which is named "firstname lastname"  It would cut the filepath off at firstname and then generate an error when running the db assembler.  I didn't have this issue at initial install since I didn't have any modules at the time and when I added them I just manually ran their SQL files.